# Trying to stub a function results in Descriptor for property is non-configurable and non-writable

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I'm trying to write out a unit test that stubs the `getSignedUrl` function from the [@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/packages/s3-request-presigner) package, however when I try stub out the function with `sinon`, I receive the error:

> - TypeError: Descriptor for property getSignedUrl is non-configurable and non-writable

```
const s3RequestSigner = require("@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner");
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const sinon = require('sinon')
....
it('should throw an error when getSignedUrl rejects', async function() {
  const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  sandbox.stub(s3RequestSigner, "getSignedUrl").rejects("fakeUrl");
  sandbox.restore();
})
```

I'm using node.js 16 and writing javascript rather than typescript.  Is there a way to mock out my function, i'm struggling to write my tests otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the following workaround for ES6 modules. You can wrap `getSignedUrl` in your own module and mock that module instead. This approach should work for any modules where sinon is unable to mock a "non-configurable and non-writable" method.

For example:

*my-s3-client-internals.js* - Your custom wrapper module

```js
// You'll need to import the original method, assign it to
// a new const, then export that const
import { getSignedUrl as getSignedUrl_orig } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';

export const getSignedUrl = getSignedUrl_orig;
```

*my-s3-client.js* - Consumer of getSignedUrl

```js
// Import the method instead from your custom file
import { getSignedUrl } from './my-s3-client-internals';

// Call it however you normally would, for example:
export const getUrl(bucket, key) {
  const command = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key });
  return getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn: 300 });
}
```

*my-s3-client.spec.js* - Unit tests for the consumer module

```js
import { getUrl } from './my-s3-client';
import * as clientInternals from './my-s3-client-internals';
import sinon from 'sinon';

it('does something', () => {
  // Mock the method exported from your wrapper module
  sinon.stub(clientInternals, 'getSignedUrl')
    .callsFake(async (client, command, options) => {
      return 'fake-url';
    });

  // Then call your consumer method to test
  const url = await getUrl('test-bucket', 'test-key');
  expect(url).to.equal('fake-url');
});
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about that, yep that's a decent solution too.

Comment: but in code coverage, the original code will still be uncovered right? because it will never get tested as now we have faked the whole function call

Comment: Now the function getSignedUrl from'./my-s3-client-internals', would get the same error "Descriptor for property getSignedUrl is non-configurable and non-writable" isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

So I won't make this the official answer, unless there are no better solutions, but this is what my research has brought about a solution.

The issue is related to this: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/2377

Where sinon will throw an error when the Object.descriptor is non-configurable.

There is no obvious way around that currently, that I can find.  The way to solve it is to use proxyquire:

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
const proxyquire =  require('proxyquire')
...
it('should throw an error when getSignedUrl rejects', async function() {
    const fakeurl = 'hello world'
    const fakeURL = sinon.stub().resolves(fakeurl)
    const handler = proxyquire(
      '../../handlers/presigned_url',
      {
        '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner': {
          'getSignedUrl': async () => {
            return fakeURL()
          }
        }
      }
    )
```

This will then resolve with whatever you want `fakeurl` to be.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use `mockery`. E.g. to mock `uuid`

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import mockery from 'mockery';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('domain/books', () => {
  let createBook;
  let uuidStub;

  before(async () => {
    mockery.enable({
      warnOnReplace: false,
      warnOnUnregistered: false,
    });
    uuidStub = sinon.stub();
    mockery.registerMock('uuid', { v4: uuidStub });

    ({ createBook } = await import('../domain/books.js'));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.resetHistory();
  });

  after(() => {
    sinon.restore();
    mockery.disable();
    mockery.deregisterAll();
  });

  describe('createBook', () => {
    it('should save a book and return the id', () => {
      const id = 'abc123';
      uuidStub.returns(id);

      const { id: bookId } = createBook({
        title: 'My Book',
        author: 'Jane Doe',
      });
      expect(bookId).to.equal(id);
    });
  });
});
```

The mockery setup is a bit tedious, but the library saved me a number of times.

Answer (score -1):

Easy to stub

```
import { createSandbox } from 'sinon';
import * as s3PresignedPost from '@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post/dist-cjs/createPresignedPost';

const sandbox = createSandbox();

const provider = new MyProvider();


describe('Generate get signed url', () => {
    it('Error', async () => {
      const errorStub = sandbox.stub(s3RequestPresigner, 'getSignedUrl').rejects(errorObject);

      const error: Error = await provider.functionCallgetSignedUrlInside(bucketName, urlPath).catch((error) => error);
      sandbox.assert.calledOnce(errorStub);
      expect(error.message).to.eq(errorObject.message);
    });

    it('Success', async () => {
      const url = `${baseUrl}/${bucketName}-${Date.now()}`;
      const successStub = sandbox.stub(s3RequestPresigner, 'getSignedUrl').resolves(url);

      const result = await storage.functionCallgetSignedUrlInside(bucketName, urlPath);
      sandbox.assert.calledOnce(successStub);
      expect(result).to.eq(url);
    });
  });
```